# Closing a dialog after starting a service using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to have a dialog trigger an intent and then close.

```
public class PinMessage extends DialogFragment {


public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    Random random = new Random();
    final int pin = random.nextInt(9000) +1000;
    builder.setMessage( "Your pin is " + (pin)+". Please note in case of password loss.")
    .setTitle("Security PIN")
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   SharedPreferences launch_track = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = launch_track.edit();
                editor1.putInt("pin", pin);
                editor1.commit();


                            //This triggers before the dialog closes
              Intent lock = new Intent(context,AppLockService.class);
                       context.startService(lock);


                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }

           }); 


    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}

}
```

On clicking the OK button, in addition to triggering the intent and starting the service, I also want the dialog to close.

Currently, when I press OK, the intent is triggered and the service starts in the background, but the dialog doesn't close and I have to press the phone button to get out of it. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
```

As you can see you have acceess to the **dialog** within the method, just invoke the dismiss:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Lol. It was so simple. Thanks for the solution. :)

Comment: waiting for it to let me :) hence the upvote for now :)

Answer (score 1):

Create the reference of the **AlertDialog**

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Start the Service and your required code
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
return alertDialog;
```

**OR**

You will get the Dialog Reference thru the **onClick**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Start the Service and your required code
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Creating this reference is unnecessary since you already have a reference in the method, (DialogInterface dialog, int which)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        //your implementation while on dismiss  
    }
});
```

Also add `dialog.dismiss();` in `onClick`